# Split a list into list of lists based on modulus of index in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'd like to write elements of lists to alternating files, and figured I would process the list before.

With a list of strings where the order is important, like `ordered_favorite_colors` =`["red", "blue", "green", "hazel"]`, and variable number of files `number_of_files`, I'd like to partition the list into multiple lists so that each file can contain my most favorite color remaining. If `number_of_files = 1`, the result would be `[["red", "blue", "green", "hazel"]]`, if `number_of_files = 3` the result would be `[["red", "hazel"], ["blue"], ["green"]]`

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: This is not a real question and it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Modulus always needs two parameters for instance, so which do you want to use for splitting the lists? Please rework your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelButscher sorry, I'll make a better effort next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

size = 3
res = [l[i::size] for i in range(size)]
```